# How can I get a session scoped bean to persist across multiple tests in Arquillian?

Tags: java, java-ee-7, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to get an Arquillian integration test working with a fairly simple SessionScoped bean that stores the login info for the current user

```
@SessionScoped
public class Session
        implements Serializable
{
    private LoginUser loginUser = null;

    // Methods for logging in, getting logged in user, checking privileges, etc.
}
```

My test class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@SessionScoped
public class SessionIntegrationTest
        implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionIntegrationTest.class);

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment()
    {
        PomEquippedResolveStage pom = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml");

        File[] guava = pom.resolve("com.google.guava:guava").withTransitivity().asFile();

        WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
                .addPackages(true, "technology.constellation")
                .addAsLibraries(guava)
                .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");;

        System.out.println(war.toString(true));

        return war;
    }

    @Inject
    private Session session;

    @Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    @InSequence(1)
    public void noLoggedInUser()
    {
        log.info("First test");
        assertEquals(false, session.isLoggedIn());
        session.getCurrentUser();
    }

    @Test
    @InSequence(2)
    public void testLogin() throws AuthenticationException
    {
        session.logIn("admin", "admin", null);
        assertNotNull(session.getCurrentUser());
        assertEquals(true, session.isLoggedIn());
    }

    @Test
    @InSequence(3)
    public void testSessionAcrossRequests()
    {
        assertTrue("Session should still be logged in", session.isLoggedIn());
    }
}
```

In this test, the first two pass and the third fails. The tests are getting a new Session bean for every test.

According to the  [Arquillian documentation](http://arquillian.org/arquillian-core/#active-scopes), the Session scope should be active across test in the same test class. So I would expect the third test to pass. I've tried with and without annotating the test class itself as SessionScoped, but no luck.

Anyone know how to get this working, or if this is even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of reading, testing, and searching (soul- and otherwise), I found that the scopes specified in the docs are active across tests only when using the weld embedded container.

Not sure why it doesn't work with others, but it would be nice if they could get that working.